# How to redirect index.php to root using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have xampp installed on windows8.1. I’ve enabled mod_rewrite in the apache conf file, and i’m using the .htaccess file .I have restarted my webserver and followed step by step instructions to enable .htaccess files and mod rewrite.

With all that in place my application resides at http://example.com/ci/

Now the problem i get is when i go to http://example.com/ci/index I get redirected to xampp splash screen. When i go to http://example.com/ci/  i’m fine. Now i have my config variable set to $config[‘index_page’] = “”; and i have the htaccess file inplace.

I may have just been staring at this to long but i have no idea what’s happening. I know it is not a CI problem and somewhere the issue has to lie with mod_rewrite but i’m fresh out of ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my .htaccess

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]


    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ci/index.php/$1 [L]

 </IfModule>

 <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: Why are you using `http://example.com/ci/index` URL and where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: Do you have a controller named Ci?It seems it send you not found page and to index.php which is xamp slash screen page

Answer (score 1):

make your htaccess file just simple as below
hope it will work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /ci/index.php/$0 [PT,L] 
RewriteBase /clientname/
```

and define a default controller in config